# How can I detect if a user is away from keyboard?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting that the user is away from the PC with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516179/detecting-that-the-user-is-away-from-the-pc-with-net)

I want to make a function which determines if someone is currently AFK or not. 
For that I want to listen to the Keyboard Keys. 
Any ideas how to realize such a function?

The normal `KeyPressed` event works only if the Form is focused, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right. You need something more global since a user will not have focus set onto a single application. Take a look at this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)/[Codeplex project](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/)

Regardless of language and framework this is how applications such as instant messengers determine whether or not a user is AFK. It should be noted though that this can be used for nefarious purposes such as key loggers.

**Abstract:**

> This class allows you to tap keyboard and mouse and/or to detect their
>   activity even when an application runs in the background or does not
>   have any user interface at all. This class raises common .NET events
>   with KeyEventArgs and MouseEventArgs, so you can easily retrieve any
>   information you need.